# Boolean Function to Evaluate string

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, data-conversion, ternary

I need to build a function that evaluates a string of numbers in C++. The string of numbers is in the [balanced ternary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_ternary) form meaning the numbers are either -1,0,or 1 to be valid. So the point of the function is to check the string to make sure it is valid. For example, if a user enters "-101-11" The boolean function would return true. Or if the user enters "-1012" The boolean function would return false. This function is also a private member function of a class. Let me show you what I've coded so far, (I know it's incorrect but if someone could help me out that would be great!) It's in C++.

```
bool BTernary::isTernary(string s)
{
    int i;
    int l = s.length();
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        if (s.at(i) == '-') {
            continue;
        }
        else if (s.at(i) == '0') {
            continue;
        }
        else if (s.at(i) == '1') {
            break;
        }

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

I've also tried a different approach to checking the string, it looks like this: (This is in a test file I've been working on for awhile and it compiles without error. The problem is if it sees a '-' or a '1' or a '0' it automatically assumes it to be true, I guess instead of evaluating the whole string for the characters I need to evaluate character by character?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i;
    string s = "0";
    for (i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (s.at(i) == '-' || '0' || '1') {
            cout << "True" << endl;
            return True;
        }
        else {
            cout << "false" << endl;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: if you get a `-` then the next character has to be a `1`; so the `continue` statement is wrong (don't forget to check he length 1st).  The code currently allows `-0`.

Comment: *Let me show you what I've coded so far, (I know it's incorrect)* - Did you put the effort into correcting your own logic?  The point of learning how to write programs is to see if you can correct your own mistakes.  You made an attempt, so go through your code with the debugger to see where the program goes against your plan.

Comment: You may want to consider using a [`std::regex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex).

Comment: `if (s.at(i)=='-'||'0'||'1'){` -- What is this line intended to do?  It doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a terser version of Mihail's suggestion:

```
bool BTernary::isTernary(const std::string& s)
{
    bool minus = false;

    for (const char c : s)
    {
       switch (c)
       {
         case '-':
            if (minus) return false;
            minus = true;
            break;

         case '0':
            if (minus) return false;
            break;

         case '1':
            if (minus) minus = false;
            break;

         default:
            return false;
    }

    return !minus;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm is easy, you should check if `-` is always followed by an `1` and that there are no other characters, only `0` and `1`

```
bool BTernary::isTernary(string s) {
    int l = s.length();
    bool minus = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        if (s[i] == '-') {
            if (minus) {
                return false;
            }
            minus = true;
        } else if (s[i] == '0') {
            if (minus) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (s[i] == '1') {
            if (minus) {
                minus = false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return !minus;
}
```

Comment: this code is crying out for a for-each loop and a switch statement